# How to import an xml correctly using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

all I'm trying to do is import an xml and turn it into a beautiful soup object.

```
r = requests.get("http://svn.testing.com:8080/env.xml", auth=creds)
print r.text    #note.. this prints the xml and everything looks correct so no problem there.
clean_xml = BeautifulSoup(open('r.text', 'r'), 'xml')
```

When I run this I get:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r.text'
```

print r.text prints as expected though.

Earlier in this project I was importing a local file with beautiful soup, and now I am importing from a url, so I don't know if that is related to the issue here.

Comment: What's  so difficult to read error message. You are opening `r.text` as file. Where are you saving it? does it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such **file** is an obvious error.

You are trying to open a file named "r.text" with `open('r.text', 'r')`

Try actually using the `r.text` variable

```
clean_xml = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')
```